# For a sequence of positive real numbers converging to a limit (which is not equal to 0), show that infimum > 0

Tags: real-analysis, limits, supremum-and-infimum

I think to do this I either need to prove the infimum is a minumum or a limit but I'm not sure how.

I have tried this:

By definition of the infimum:
" Let A be a subset of the real numbers and b be a real number.
Then b is the infimum of A if:
(i) b≤a for all a ∈ A
(ii) c≤a for all a ∈ A will imply that c≤b."

We know for all a ∈ A, a>0.
If we consider the second case, this means the infimum (b) is such that 0≤b.

We can assume for a contradiction that b = 0 in order to leave just the case 0 < b.
b cannot be the minimum of the set, as all a > 0.
***because all the terms are positive, for the infimum to be 0, it means the limit of the series is zero (and the sequence must be decreasing)***, but L cannot be equal to 0 so we have a contradiction.

***This highlighted bit is the jump I'm struggling with.***

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  you can use the fact the sequence converges to say the inf of all the numbers past some point $N$ is greater than, say, half the limit.  Just get $N$ from whoever told you the sequence converges by giving them $\epsilon$ as half the limit.  Now there are only finitely many numbers out to $N$.

Comment: Doesn't that assume it's a decreasing sequence?

Comment: @timtfj:  Not at all.  As long as the sequence converges to $L$, there is some $N$ so that all the terms past $N$ are within $(\frac L2, \frac {3L}2)$ by using the $\epsilon-N$ definition with $\epsilon=\frac L2$.  It can bounce around however it wants.

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood what you mean, but II if for example it converges upwards to the infimum of the sequence, the whole sequence is below its own infimum, surely? So the infimum isn't the infimum.

Comment: @timtfj:  No the inf of the sequence is the largest number that is less than or equal to all the terms of the sequence.  If it is increasing all the terms are below the limit.  If the sequence is $1-\frac 1n$ for $n=3,4,5,\ldots$ the limit is $1$ but the inf is $\frac 23$

Comment: My problem is that the first sentence of your answer, seems to say that the infimum (past some N) *is* the limit. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @timtfj:  yes, you are misunderstanding.  The point of the problem is that you can have a set of positive numbers with infimum $0$.  An example would be the sequence $\frac 1n$.  We want to prove that if you have a sequence of positive numbers that converges to a positive limit, the infimum of the set is strictly positive.  I am saying that all the terms past $N$ are at least $\frac L2$, so the inf of all those terms is at least $\frac L2$.

Comment: Now I realise I was misreading an ambiguous phrase: parsing it as *the sequence converges to, say, the inf of all the numbers...* Amazingly most of the sentence still holds together when misread that way! Sorry for the bafflement.

Answer (score 1):

Outline of what I'd try:

The limit can't be negative, since then terms approaching it would be negative. Its not allowed to be zero, so is positive.

Call the sequence $(x_n)$ and the limit $k$. Choose an $\epsilon$ such that $k-\epsilon >0$.

Beyond some $n=N$, all $x_n>k-\epsilon$ because of the convergence.

The first $N$ terms are all positive by definition, and have a minimum value $m$.

If the infimum is below both $m$ and $k-\epsilon$ it can't meet the definition of an infimum. So it's $\ge$ the lower of them, which is positive. Therefore the infimum is positive.

I think that does it, once it's translated into more precise language. (My aim here is to make it as human-readable as I can, to make clear how it works.)

Comment: This is an elaboration of my hint.  I thought it better to leave more to OP.

Comment: It is, but as I totally misread your hint I didn't know I was elaborating it. I only realised the correct reading just now. My initial version of this was pretty vague and and in the end I decided enough hours had gone past for more detail to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that $ \ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = L \neq 0 \ $. As $ \ \frac{|L|}{2}>0 \ $, by definition, there exists $ \ N \in \mathbb{N} \ $ such that, for all $ \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ $, if $ \ n>N \ $, then $ \ |x_n - L|< \frac{|L|}{2} \ $.

Let $ \ A = \{ 0,1,2,3,...,N \} \subset \mathbb{N} \ $, $ \ B = \mathbb{N} \setminus A = \{ N+1, N+2, N+3, ... \} \subset \mathbb{N} \ $ and $$m= \min \{ x_0 , x_1, x_2 , x_3 , ... , x_N \} \ .$$ Then $ \ \mathbb{N} = A \cup B \ $ and $ \ A \cap B = \varnothing \ $. Hence, for all $ \ n \in \mathbb{N} \, $, we have either $ \ $ **(i)** $ \ n \in A \ $ or $ \ $ **(ii)** $ \ n \in B \ $, for which

> **(i)** $ \ $ if $ \ n \in A \ $, then $ \ 0 < m \leq x_n \ $ ;

and

> **(ii)** $ \ $ if $ \ n \in B \ $, then $ \ n \in \mathbb{N} \ $ and $ \ n >N \ $ and we have that $ \ |x_n - L|< \frac{|L|}{2} \ $. Therefore $$|L| -|x_n| \leq \big| |L| - |x_n| \big| \leq |L - x_n| = |x_n - L| < \frac{|L|}{2} \ , $$ that is, $$x_n = |x_n|>|L|- \frac{|L|}{2}= \frac{|L|}{2} >0 \ . $$

Choosing $ \ c = \min \left\{ m , \frac{|L|}{2} \right\} \ $, we get that $ \ x_n \geq c>0 \ $, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. So $ \ c>0 \ $ and $c$ is a lower bound for $(x_n)$. We conclude that $ \ \displaystyle \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}} x_n \geq c > 0 \ $.

Comment: This is what I hoped I could get OP to produce.

Answer (score 0):

When studying new mathematical material, an attempt must be made be to write down 'the setup' in a mathematically precise way, and to avoid using logical arguments that use the informal language of, say, English.

The setup:

$\tag 1 \lim\limits_{n \to +∞} a_n = L, \text{ with } L \gt 0 \text{ and } a_n \gt 0$

$\tag 2 A = \{ a_n \, | \, n \in \mathbb N\}$

$\tag 3 b = \text{inf}(A)$

Assume $b = 0$.

Using open intervals of the form $(0, \varepsilon)$, a strictly decreasing sequence  $b_n$ with $b_n \in A$ can be constructed such that

$\tag 4 \lim\limits_{n \to +∞} b_n = 0$

Now $b_n$ might not be a subsequence of $a_n$, but you can take another pass over it, throwing out terms if necessary to get the desired subsequence. Since every subsequence of $(a_n)_{ \, n \in \mathbb N} $must have the same limit, $L = 0$, we arrive at a contradiction.

Note that you can construct $b_n$ as a subsequence on the first pass, but thought it might be easier to follow by breaking it into two steps. The basic truth is that for any finite set of positive numbers, an $\varepsilon \gt 0$ can be found such that the open interval $(0, \varepsilon)$ is disjoint from that set.

---

The OP states in bold

> it means the limit of the series is zero (and the sequence must be
>   decreasing)

Let $(a_n)_{ \, n \in \mathbb N} $ be defined by

$$   
    a_n  = \left\{\begin{array}{lr}
        \frac{1}{n+1}, & \text{for } n \text{ even }\\
       \frac{1}{n-.5}, & \text{for } n \text{ odd }
        \end{array}\right\} 
$$

This sequence of positive numbers converges to $0$, but it is not a decreasing sequence
(see the [wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Increasing_and_decreasing)).